# The tangent to the curve $y = x^3-3x^2-8x+5$ at point A goes through point $C(-13,-3)$.

Tags: calculus

The tangent to the curve $y = x^3-3x^2-8x+5$ at point A goes through point $C(-13,-3)$. The gradient of the curve at point $A$ is $p$

(i) Find the equation of the line through $A$ and $C$ in terms of $p$.
(ii) Use differentiation to obtain another equation involving $p$.
(iii) Hence by eliminating $p$ and $y$, find the cubic equation in $x$ that represents the possible positions of the x-coordinate of $A$.

(i) $y+3=p(x+13) \Rightarrow y=px+13p -3$
(ii) $y = x^3-3x^2-8x+5 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2-6x-8=p$

I'm not sure how to go about solving part (iii). How do I eliminate $p$ and $y$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Substitute $y = x^3 -3x^2-8x+5$ and $p = 3x^2-6x-8$ into $y = px+13p-3$.

Comment: so $x^3-3x^2-8x+5=(3x^2-6x-8)x+13(3x^2-6x-8)-3 \Rightarrow 0 = 2x^3+36x^2-78x-112 $